# how to check every value in row of datatable using c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datatable, datarow

I  have two tables called `visits` and `members`  and i am getting the data by using following query..

```
 string sql=  @"SELECT member_Firstname, member_Lastname, member_Postcode,  
          visit_DateTime, visit_Status, visit_Logout_DateTime, visits.member_Id, visit_AlertMsg
          FROM members, visits
          WHERE members.member_Id = visits.member_Id
          AND members.member_Active LIKE 'y%'";
```

at here i am getting  the visit_DateTime values with by using some comparisons with combobox values

```
    datatable dt = helper.getdata(sql)
     foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
     {
         if (row["visit_Logout_DateTime"] != null)
         {
          DateTime dtlogout = DateTime.Parse(row["visit_Logout_DateTime"].ToString());
          if (dtlogout != null)
          {
            if (cbPeriod.Text == "Today")
            {
              newItem.lblTime.Text = dtlogout.ToString("HH':'mm':'ss");

            }
            else
              newItem.lblTime.Text = dtlogout.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'  -  'HH':'mm':'ss");
          }
        }

     }
```

but i got the error at this line `DateTime dtlogout = DateTime.Parse(row["visit_Logout_DateTime"].ToString());`

**error :** `string was not recognised as valid datetime (because of one value in that row is empty)`

the row `"visit_Logout_DateTime"`

i have got the values of  `"visit_Logout_DateTime"` like this....

```
firstname     lastname   postcode      visit_Logout_DateTime
-------------  --------   ---------      ---------------------
 rob            peter     hhd344h            
 peter         chan        hy78kjk         2011-09-08 12:09:08
 rock          sam        yudufg3746h      2011-08-08 09:08:45
```

i have tried that for checking the empty values of this  visit_Logout_DateTime like i mentioned above..

but i have failed for chacking ever value is empty or not in that row...

how to check every value in this row  (row["visit_Logout_DateTime"]) is empty or not

would any one pls help me  on this guys ...

many thanks....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of checking if the column is `null`, you should check if the contents of the column are `null`. You can do that by comparing it to `DBNull.Value`:

```
if (row["visit_Logout_DateTime"] != DBNull.Value)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing - use TryParse, not Parse to parse values when you're not sure whether the value will be a valid object or not.

For checking all values, try the following code example for checking each value:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyTable");

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                if (row[column] != null)
                {
                    string value = row[column].ToString();
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                    {
                        // Do something
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks... but i need to check every value in that row whether it is null or empty and i have tried String.IsNullOrEmpty but still i  am getting same error

Comment: Try that solution with below Kristof's idea

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTime.TryParse` like this:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime();

if (DateTime.TryParse(row["visit_Logout_DateTime"], out date))
            dtlogout = date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check row against `null`. You should compare to `DBNull.Value`.
So, either go with:

```
row["visit_Logout_DateTime"] != DBNull.Value
```

or

```
!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row["visit_Logout_DateTime"].ToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Kristof's answer you could look at extension methods to tidy the code up a little;

```
 public static DateTime? GetDate( this DataRow Row, string ColumnName )
    {

        object Value = Row[ ColumnName ];

        if( Value == DBNull.Value )
            return null;
        else
            return (DateTime)Value;

    }

// Repeat for other types, or use a generic version.
...

DateTime? dtlogout = row.GetDate("visit_Logout_DateTime");
```

Note the use of the Nullable DateTime (trailing ?) so that it can accept nulls.